# ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 5 but expected 4 for input 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, inference

I have used Tensorflow's object detection API on Mobilenet SSD v1, to train on my data. I converted it to tflite, and now am facing this error at time of inference. Below is my inference code.

```
# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter("model.tflite")
#allocate the tensors
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

#get input and output tensors
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

import cv2
# Read the image and decode to a tensor
image_path='117.jpg' 
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
#Preprocess the image to required size and cast
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_tensor= np.array(np.expand_dims(img,0), dtype=np.uint8)

#set the tensor to point to the input data to be inferred
input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, [input_tensor])
#Run the inference
interpreter.invoke()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
results = np.squeeze(output_data)
top_k = results.argsort()
for label, idx in train_data_gen.class_indices.items():  
    if top_k[idx]==1:
        print("Prediction: ",label)
```

Following test code runs without error

```
import numpy as np

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.uint8)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```